# What do I do with the recovered lost partition

Tags: partitioning

I recovered my lost Ubuntu 949 GB partition and it is on the launcher below the OS file when running the live cd. How to I integrate it into a running Ubuntu program?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attempt to do this, which I don't recommend doing because the data might be corrupted, since it's been recovered, you should [reinstall grub using boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I can't stress enough, though, that you should ***backup your data to an online cloud or another hard disk*** first before attempting this, and don't expect it to work 100%.

Comment: Thanks for the information but the partition just sits on the launcher and all I can do is open it and look at the contents. I have no idea how to copy a 949GB partition. Any suggestions? Can I install Ubuntu from the live CD and will the lost partition become a part of the new installation?

Comment: When I right click my only options are Open, Unlock from Launcher and Unmount

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer, you will be able to find directions for reinstalling grub using boot-repair. That will make the partition bootable.